# ggplot how to create paired error bars

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, visualization

I have estimates for a pair of outcomes from the same model and I want to show these results using error bars.  How can I create a pair of plot that compares estimates of rea in the sample data with all others (rea and sci, rea and mat etc..). In all the plots rea should always appear as a first in the plot and the order of the data should not change.

```
       library (ggplot2) 
ucl<- c(5.88 , 3.92,  7.0,  3.724,  5.488) 
lcl<-c(1.04 ,  0.04,  2.04, -0.06   , 0.84) 
est<-c(3 , 2,   4,  1.9,    2.8) 
df<-data.frame (cbind(est,ucl, lcl))

df$labels<-c("sci","rea","mat","apt","hor")
```

This code creates individual plots, but my need is a pair of plots comparing rea with others.

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x = labels, y = est,ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl))  +
    geom_point(position=position_dodge() ,size = 2.5) + 
    geom_linerange(position=position_dodge(), size =0.5) +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your data frame to get desired result.

First, make data frame `df2` that contains one line for each level of `sci`, `mat`, `apt` and `hor` and four lines of `rea`. Then make column `labels` as factor with levels in order you need (`rea` as first, then all other levels). Add column `labels2` that contains the same level names as `labels` except `rea` and each level is used twice (once for the same level and once for `rea`).

```
df2<-rbind(df[-2,],df[rep(2,4),])
df2$labels<-factor(df2$labels,levels=c("rea","sci","mat","apt","hor"))
df2$labels2<-factor(rep(c("sci","mat","apt","hor"),times=2),
                     levels=c("sci","mat","apt","hor")) 
df2
   est   ucl   lcl labels labels2
1  3.0 5.880  1.04    sci     sci
3  4.0 7.000  2.04    mat     mat
4  1.9 3.724 -0.06    apt     apt
5  2.8 5.488  0.84    hor     hor
2  2.0 3.920  0.04    rea     sci
21 2.0 3.920  0.04    rea     mat
22 2.0 3.920  0.04    rea     apt
23 2.0 3.920  0.04    rea     hor
```

Now use `df2` for the plotting of your data - `labels` are used for x axis but `labels2` for the facets. Add `scales="free_x"` inside `facet_wrap()` to remove unused levels in each facet.

```
ggplot(df2,aes(x = labels, y = est,ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl))  +
  geom_point(size = 2.5) + 
  geom_linerange(size =0.5) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~labels2,scales="free_x")
```

[image]

### UPDATE

To get all lineranges in one plot add to dataframe `df2` (made in example above) column `type` with two levels - `rea` and `other`.

```
df2$type<-rep(c("other","rea"),each=4)
```

Then use `labels2` as x values and `type` to set `color=` or `shape=`, or just `group=` for lineranges.

```
ggplot(df2,aes(x = labels2, y = est,ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl,color=type,shape=type))+
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=0.5) ,size = 2.5) + 
  geom_linerange(position=position_dodge(width=0.5), size =0.5) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: @redmode and Didzis, what I want to have is 4 pairs of plots in one graph. Example of plot that I want to have can be found on the following link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwzmHP4sr2DdUXFPbkNvTUhZMlk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Meso you would get the answer earlier if you added sample image to your question because without image it was hard to understand

Answer (score 3):

If I got it correctly, you need facets. It can be like this:

```
# Additional column for faceting
df$not.rea <- df$labels!="rea"

# Your solution + facet_grid with labeller and free scales/space
ggplot(df, aes(x=labels, y=est, ymin=lcl, ymax=ucl)) +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(), size=2.5) + 
  geom_linerange(position=position_dodge(), size=0.5) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=1)) +
  facet_grid(~not.rea, scales="free", space="free", 
             labeller=function(var,val) c("rea","other")[val+1])
```

It produces:

[image]

But if you want face-to-face comparison of each estimation to rea, you can subset `data.frame` which is passed to `ggplot2`, i.e. for rea vs. mat:

```
ggplot(df[df$labels %in% c("rea","mat"),], ...) + ...
```

**UPDATE:**

In order to produce 4 plots you can use this approach:

```
# Convert labels to factor - rea should always be first
df$labels <- factor(df$labels, levels=c("rea","sci","mat","apt","hor"))

# Plotting function
one.plot <- function(filter){
  ggplot(df[df$labels %in% c("rea",filter),], aes(x=labels, y=est, ymin=lcl, ymax=ucl)) +
    geom_point(position=position_dodge(), size=2.5) + 
    geom_linerange(position=position_dodge(), size=0.5) +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=1)) +
    facet_grid(~labels, scales="free", space="free")
}

# Runner of the batch
sapply(as.character(df$labels[df$labels != "rea"]), function(s) print(one.plot(s)) )
```

It shows 4 plots. If you want to save them as separate files, you can modify the runner like this:

```
sapply(as.character(df$labels[df$labels != "rea"]), function(s) ggsave(paste0(s,".png"), one.plot(s)) )
```

It saves 4 `*.png` files to working directory.

**UPDATE 2:**

To produce 4 pairs of errorbars in single plot, you can utilize `gridExtra` package. It's as easy as:

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(one.plot("sci"),
             one.plot("mat"),
             one.plot("apt"),
             one.plot("hor"),
             ncol=2, main="Main Title")
```

Which produces:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. However, what I want is two pairs of plots for rea and the rest. Thus I need a total of 4 pairs of error bars, each time with rea.

Comment: @Meso So, you need 4 separate plots? Each plot is rea vs other estimate? In this case you can call `ggplot` 4 times each time subsetting `df` like in last line in the answer.

Comment: Do you mean I should run ggplot2 4 times? That is a bit excessive.

Comment: Thanks again. What I really want is 4 pairs of error bars in a single plot. Sorry for misunderstanding.